# Why do I need a direct access to the view container instead of accessing it's view controller's view in order to animate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a setup of one view controller with several container views within it, each with their own corresponding view controllers. In the code for the view controller containing all of them I have the embedded/child view controllers as properties, which I set in `prepareForSegue`, as they're embed segues.

Now if I try to access the view of one of the child view controllers, such as `childViewController.view.frame` in order to move it, when I try to move it just pushes it over a little bit inside the view controller without actually moving the view controller itself.

However, if in the Storyboard I create an outlet to each container view in the one containing view controller, and use `childView.frame`, it animates fine moving the FULL view controller properly.

Why is this? Aren't they both referencing the same view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not referencing the same view. childView is just a regular UIView, that's a subview of the container controller. childViewController.view is the view of the child view controller -- that view is a subview of childView. So, if you want to move the child view controller's view, you need to move its superview, childView (both of those views have the same size, so you can't move the child view controller's view within childView without it going out of bounds).

What you're doing in IB, is equivalent to this in code (where childVC is the embedded view controller, and containerView is the subview in the parent). This code would be in the container controller.

```
[self addChildViewController: childVC];
[childVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
childVC.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds; 
[self.containerView addSubview:childVC.view];
```